# Is there a way to list task properties in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

There is a command that lists all tasks (`gradle tasks`) accessible at project level which I am using very often when while working with Gradle. Is there a way to see properties available inside each of those tasks? I want to be able to do something like that:

```
gradle properties compileJava        #this should list all properties available in **compileJava** task
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is `gradle help --task compileJava`.

This will indicate which projects do define the `compileJava` task and also tell you what is the type of the task.
With this type, you can consult the [DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html) to get information about the available properties.

There is no tool part of the Gradle CLI (at this time - Gradle 6.0.1) that will give you this in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Many properties are not exposed via `gradle help --task XXX`. Use `gradle model` to get the list of all available tasks: it prints the class baking the task. Get the source code for the class.

Alternative way is via logging (run `gradle bump`):

```
tasks.register("dump") {
    doLast{
        logger.lifecycle("type: {}", bootJar.properties);
    }
}
```